# How can I make the sidebar stick?

Tags: html, css

Currently, I've made it so that the sidebar appears where the 'apply' page starts. I want the sidebar to then remain in that position as the user continues to scroll down. Another thing that confuses me is that when I set the position to 'absolute' for the bar, it just disappears completely. Why does this happen?

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: right;
}

#navbar-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}

#apply {
    background-color: red;
}

#about {
    background-color: orange;
}

#sponsor {
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pages">
    <!-- apply page -->
    <div id="apply" class="sections" tabindex='2'>
        <!-- navigation bar -->
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul id="navbar-links">
                <li>Apply</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Sponsor</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <!-- about page -->
    <div id="about" class="sections" tabindex='3'>
        <div class="container">

        </div>        
    </div>

    <!-- sponsor page -->
    <div id="sponsor" class="sections" tabindex='4'>
        <div class="container">

        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: fixed` might be what your looking for.

Comment: ^That doesn't work. It just makes the sidebar disappear

Comment: You'll need JavaScript: The CSS has to change when you reach the "apply" page. And `position:fixed` will work if you position the nav-bar correctly.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: What do you mean? @Sarcoma

Comment: Did you manage to get the sidebar to work how you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: fixed` fix the position to the view.

You can then use: `top` `right` `left` and `bottom` to put the element where you want it to be. So `right: 0;` and `top: 0;` put the element 0px from the right and top.

The same is true for position absolute, if you didn't use any of those that may be why it disappeared.

See here for more details on css position property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

```css
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#navbar-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}

#apply {
    background-color: red;
}

#about {
    background-color: orange;
}

#sponsor {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="pages">
    <!-- apply page -->
    <div id="apply" class="sections" tabindex='2'>
        <!-- navigation bar -->
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul id="navbar-links">
                <li>Apply</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Sponsor</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <!-- about page -->
    <div id="about" class="sections" tabindex='3'>
        <div class="container">

        </div>        
    </div>

    <!-- sponsor page -->
    <div id="sponsor" class="sections" tabindex='4'>
        <div class="container">

        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```